org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for wattzhub.account.UpdatePage$$Lambda
I have a problem with selenium test using java, I want to upload a profile photo but I found errors. Everything works well at first, the photo is downloaded but it does not appear on the screen and the validation button is not clickable knowing that all the paths are 100% correct. I tried several solutions like forcing the click, checking that the button is no longer deactivated,I increased the implicit time but still it doesn't work. This is the response I receive when I run my code:
File sent : C:\Users\KATANA\Desktop
Image loaded correctly: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgAAIAAAUAAarVyFEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for wattzhub.account.UpdatePage$$Lambda/0x000001b40122a6f8@5a62b2a4 (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
I hope you can help me resolve this problem and thank you very much in advance.
    public void changeProfilePicture(String imagePath) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        By modifyButton = By.xpath("//button[@class='p-element p-button-outlined p-button-secondary ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 mb-3 p-button p-component']");
        WebElement modifyButtonElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(modifyButton));
        modifyButtonElement.click();

        By pictureDownload = By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//span[@class='input-browse']");
        WebElement pictureDownloadElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pictureDownload));
        pictureDownloadElement.click();

        By modalContent = By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']");
        WebElement modalElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(modalContent));
        delay(1000);

        By fileInput = By.id("file-upload");
        WebElement fileInputElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(fileInput));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='block'; arguments[0].style.opacity='1';", fileInputElement);

        fileInputElement.sendKeys(imagePath);
        System.out.println("File sent : " + imagePath);

        By imageElement = By.xpath("//img[contains(@class, 'source-image')]");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(imageElement));
        WebElement image = driver.findElement(imageElement);


        js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", image);


        wait.until(driver -> {
            String visibility = image.getCssValue("visibility");
            return visibility.equals("visible");
        });

        // Validez l'attribut src
        String srcValue = image.getAttribute("src");
        if (srcValue.startsWith("data:image/png;base64,")) {
            System.out.println("Image loaded correctly: " + srcValue);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Image not loaded or invalid src.");
        }
}


the error seems to happen after this method is called.  btw, the image may not have been uploaded or "sent" at this point.  It could show a preview client-side.  From the error message it seems like you are expecting a redirect to happen... you may need to submit the form.  If the submit is happening, it may take longer than 10 seconds for submission.
